# A way to intervene "after" in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have written a tcl script where there is wait for 20 seconds in between.
Sometimes I have to come out of the waiting (or rather stop ) in between.
I have used:
`after 20000`

Is there a way to stop the waiting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of my previous projects at work, I had to deal with a similar situation where my scripts wait for N seconds, then continue on, unless the user hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then the wait is canceled. Below is my script, reduced to bare essential to show how it works.

```
package require Tclx

proc abortTest {} {
    after cancel $::afterId
    set ::status "Ctrl+C detected"
}

#
# Main
#

puts "start"
set status "Ctrl+C not detected"

# when Ctrl+c detected, call abortTest
signal trap SIGINT abortTest

# Wait for N seconds
set WAIT_TIME 10000
set afterId [after $WAIT_TIME {set status "Exit normally"}]
puts "Wait for [expr {$WAIT_TIME / 1000}] seconds"
vwait status; # wait until status changed

puts $status
puts "end"
```

## Discussion

- The `signal` command said, "if the user hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then call `abortTest`"
- Notice that in this form, the `after` command will exit right away, but the TCL interpreter will execute the `set status ...` command 10 seconds later.
- The `vwait` command waits until the variable `status` to change its value.
- After 10 seconds, if the user had not hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then the variable `status` will be set to *"Exit normally"*, at that time, the `vwait` command exits
- If the user hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> during that time, then `status` will be changed and the `vwait` command exits

## Update

While reducing the original script, I took out the part to cancel the after command. Now I am putting it back in. Notice that the `after` command returns an ID, which I used in `abortTest` to cancel the action.

Answer (score 3):

If you just use:

```
after 20000
```

Then no, there's no way (other than killing the process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or `kill`, of course).

If you want an interruptable wait in Tcl, use this:

```
after 20000 set done 1
vwait done
```

That will continue to service events and so can be interrupted. Save the token returned by `after 20000 set done 1` and you can cancel the timer (e.g., if you want to reschedule it). Set the (global `done`) variable yourself otherwise and you'll finish waiting sooner.

Comment: Straight `after 20000` isn't actually used all that often by most Tclers precisely because it doesn't do _anything_ else…